# Calculating distribution of items among cells with limited capacity

Tags: combinatorics

The questioning is:

> Given 13 identical balls and 6 different cells, in how many ways can the balls be distributed between the cells so that there is not a single cell that has 3 balls?

My approach to the question was:

- Calculate the amount of distributions with no additional terms, which is D(6,13) and then subtract the amount of distribiotions that has at least one cell that has 3 balls.
- To calculate the amount of distribiotions that has at least one cell that has 3 balls, I need to calculate the amount of distribiotions that has 1 cell with 3 balls, 2 cells with 3 balls etc... Until 4 cells as 5 cells with 3 balls is impossible given there are only 13 balls. Then apply the inclusion exclusion principle on the solution to find the total amount of distribiotions in which there are n cells, 0 < n < 5 that has 3 balls
- To calculate for n 3-balls-cells, I calculated in how many ways the balls can be distributed among the free capacity cells (e.g 6-n cells) which is D(13 - n * 3, 6-n), then multiplied by all the possible positions in which the 3-balls-cells can be in which is C(6,n), and finally subtracted the duplicated calculations (such as the 3,5 cells and the 5,3 cells counted twice) by subtracting P(6, n).

By this calculation, since all the groups are contained within the group of one 3-balls-cell the inclusion exclusion principle will only be to calculate the amount distributions of one 3-balls-cell:

```
D(6,13) - C(6,1) * D(10,5) =
8568 - 6 * 2002 = -3444
```

Which doesn't make any sense.

What have I done wrong and what is the way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can a cell have four balls? Or is the restriction that no cell has $3$ or more balls?

Comment: @Tomas Andrews the restriction is there sould be not a single cell with exactly 3 balls. Cells can be empty, have 1,2,4 or even 13 balls, as long as there are no cells with 3 balls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have started the inclusion-exclusion calculation but not finished it. Here’s a complete working out:

Let $A_i$ be the set of distributions in which cell $i$ has $3$ balls. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^6A_i\right|&=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[6]}(-1)^{|I|+1}\left|\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\right|\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^4(-1)^{k+1}\binom6k\binom{(13-3k)+(6-k-1)}{6-k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^4(-1)^{k+1}\binom6k\binom{18-4k}{5-k}\;,
\end{align*}$$

since it is impossible for more than $4$ cells to contain $3$ balls, so the number of good distributions is

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{18}5&-\sum_{k=1}^4(-1)^{k+1}\binom6k\binom{18-4k}{5-k}\\
&=\binom{18}5+\sum_{k=1}^4(-1)^k\binom6k\binom{18-4k}{5-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^4(-1)^k\binom6k\binom{18-4k}{5-k}\\
&=\binom{18}5-\binom61\binom{14}4+\binom62\binom{10}3-\binom63\binom62+\binom62\binom21\\
&=8568-6\cdot1001+15\cdot120-20\cdot15+15\cdot2\\
&=4092\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: +1 but the term for $k=6$ in general is not $\binom66\binom{n-19}{-1},$ unless you define $$\binom m{-1}=\begin{cases}1&m=-1\\0&m\neq-1\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Thomas: I may be missing the obvious, but I don’t see where you’re getting $n-19$. (But I should probably edit to change the upper limit of summation to $4$ anyway.)

Comment: If the number of balls is $n$ rather than $13$ then the term for $k=6$ you get is $\binom{n+5-4\cdot 6}{-1}$

Comment: @Thomas: Ah, okay; I was thinking strictly in terms of the present problem.

Answer (score 1):

The generating function for each cell is:

$$1+x+x^2+x^4+x^5+\cdots =\frac1{1-z}-z^3$$

and the generating function for the six bins is:

$$F(z)=\left(\frac1{1-z}-z^3\right)^6$$

This gives

$$\begin{align}F(z)=&\frac1{(1-z)^6}\\&-\binom61\frac{z^3}{(1-z)^5}\\&+\binom62\frac{z^6}{(1-z)^4}\\&-\binom63\frac{z^9}{(1-z)^3}\\
&+\binom64\frac{z^{12}}{(1-z)^2}\\
&-\binom65\frac{z^{15}}{1-z}\\
&+\binom66z^{18}
\end{align}$$

The coefficient of $z^n$ in $F(z)$ is thus:

$$\binom{n+5}5-6\binom{n+1}{4}+15\binom{n-3}3-20\binom{n-7}{2}+15\binom{n-11}1-6\binom{n-15}{0}+\delta_{18,n}$$

Where $\delta_{m,n}=\begin{cases}1&m=n\\0&m\neq n\end{cases}$.

Now compute for $n=13.$

---

You get the same formula if you apply inclusion-exclusion to $A,$ the set of all non-negative integer solutions to $x_1+\cdots+x_6=n$ and $A_i$ the set of solutions with $x_i=3.$

---

Another generating function approach is to notices that $\frac{1}{1-z}-z^3=\frac{1-z^3+z^4}{1-z}.$ Then:

$$F(z)=\frac{(1-z^3+z^4)^6}{(1-z)^6}$$

And $$\begin{align}(1-z^3+z^4)^6=z^{24} &- 6 z^{23} + 15 z^{22} - 20 z^{21} + 21 z^{20} \\&- 36 z^{19} + 61 z^{18} - 60 z^{17} + 45 z^{16} \\&- 66 z^{15} + 90 z^{14} - 60 z^{13} + 35 z^{12} \\&- 60 z^{11} + 60 z^{10} - 20 z^{9} + 15 z^8 \\&- 30 z^7 + 15 z^6 + 6 z^4 - 6 z^3 + 1\end{align}$$

So you get the coefficient of $z^n$ is:

$$\binom{n+5}{5}-6\binom{n+2}{5}+6\binom{n+1}{5}+16\binom{n-1}{5}\\-30\binom{n-2}{5}+\cdots-6\binom{n-18}{5}+\binom{n-19}{5}$$

Where there are $22$ terms. That's much less useful than the original answer.

Comment: +1 for using generating functions